# What I did wrong when making GAN and opening the hdf5 files?

Tags: python, numpy, generative-adversarial-network

I am making a GAN projects.
I am using the fundamental codes from , written by Tariq Rashid.

Original code is this.

```
     with h5py.File('mount/My Drive/Colab 
     Notebooks/myo_gan/celeba_dataset/celeba_aligned_small.h5py', 'r') as file_object:

     for group in file_object:
         print(group)
         pass

    with h5py.File('mount/My Drive/Colab 
    Notebooks/myo_gan/celeba_dataset/celeba_aligned_small.h5py', 'r') as file_object:
    dataset = file_object['img_align_celeba']
    image = numpy.array(dataset['6.jpg'])
    plt.imshow(image, interpolation='none')
    pass
```

and I revised for my project like this one.

```
    with h5py.File('mount/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Pogba/pogba.h5py', 'r') as file_object:

    for group in file_object:
        print(group)
        pass

    with h5py.File('mount/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Pogba/pogba.h5py', 'r') as file_object:
    dataset = file_object['pogba']
    image = numpy.array(dataset['2021-09-06T230508.713.jpg'])
    plt.imshow(image, interpolation='none')
    pass
```

and I got error messages in **dataset = file_object['pogba']**
What's wrong that I made?

Comment: What error messages did you get exactly?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Unable to open object (object 'pogba' doesn't exist)